# Initialize a singleton class when app is lunching

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, nsoperation, uiapplicationdelegate

I have singleton DB object that I want to upload from files or from server when the application starts.

I have a splash screen - after this screen I want to decide if I will go to home view controller (user already login) or to login view controller (user first time login).

I was thinking to initialize the singleton using `NSOperation` and use `NSOperationQueue`.

I want to know where is the best place to initialize this singleton. 
`application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` or another place?

Answer (score 1):

In my code I usually do the following.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // othere code here

    // Initialize ApplicationManager
    [ApplicationManager takeOff:@"TOKEN HERE"];

    return YES;
}
```

This approach is used by the old TestFlight SDK or by CocoaLumberjack. If your database setup could freeze the UI you could think to move code in background.